# Error messages on new line

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Part of Action:

```
var query = from state in ModelState.Values
            from error in state.Errors
            select error.ErrorMessage;
var errorList = query.ToList();               
return Json(new { Result = "Failed", Message = errorList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Part of script:

```
for (var error in response.Message)
{
    $('.validation-summary-errors').append(error + '<br />');
}
$('.validation-summary-errors').append(response.Message)
```

Question:
Here i'm trying to display the each error message on new line on view which is coming from action but when i'm iterating the Message then it is giving only index values i.e integer values like 0,1.

but $('.validation-summary-errors').append(response.Message) this line gives actual error messages but they separated by (,) how to display each error on new line?

Comment: `$.each(response.Message, function(index, error) { $('.validation-summary-errors').append(error + '<br />'); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var error in response.Message)
{
    $('.validation-summary-errors').append(response.Message[error] + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
$('.validation-summary-errors').append(response.Message.join('<br>'));
```